# different form override for node/add and node/edit pages?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-forms

Hia

I am using the following in a custom module to customise the form on the node/add/baby page for my BABY content type, however i want to make some slight modifications to this page when its the node/nid/edit page for the baby content type. is this possible?

```
<code>
<?php
function concept_theme() {
  return array(
    'baby_node_form' => array(
      'arguments' => array(
          'form' => NULL,
      ),
      'template' => 'templates/baby-node-form',
      'render element' => 'form',
    ),
  );
}
?>
</code>
```

thank u

Answer (score 2):

In template.php

```
function my_theme_name_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)
$hooks['baby_node_form']=array(
    'render element'=>'form',
    'template'      =>'templates/node--baby-edit',
);
return $hooks;
}
```

In node--baby-edit.tpl.php

Hide fields like this:

```
<?php hide($form['title']); ?>
```

Manipulate fields like this:

```
<?php print render($form['field_image']); ?>
```

Use this to print all/rest of content:

```
<?php print drupal_render_children($form); ?>
```

Clear cache.

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the node creation form by implementing this hook,
something similar to this:

```
hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'node_baby_form') {
     //do modification to form array $form
  }
}
```

Or if your node is defined by hook_node_info (which I believe is not the case), just changing the elements in hook_form()